# Issue in migrating OAuth2 SSO provider of Spring boot application from one provider to another

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

I am working with migrating `OAuth2` `SSO` provider for my Spring boot application from `SSOProvider1` to `SSOProvider2`.
My application has been working fine with `SSOProvider1`. The relevant properties are as follows:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider1.client-id=abcd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider1.client-secret=1234
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider1.scope=api
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider1.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider1.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ssprovider1.token-uri=https://ssoprovidr1.base.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ssprovider1.authorization-uri=https://ssoprovidr1.base.com/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ssprovider1.user-info-uri=https://ssoprovidr1.base.com/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ssprovider1.user-name-attribute=name
```

Now, as part of migration, for `SSOProvider2`, I have changed only following values:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider2.client-id=efgh
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider1.client-secret=5678
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider2.scope=read
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider2.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.ssprovider2.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ssprovider2.token-uri=https://ssoprovidr2.base.com/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.ssprovider2.authorization-uri=https://ssoprovidr2.base.com/authorize
```

But, whenever I am starting my app and browsing the end-point, I am getting following error: `Too many redirect` and clearing the browser cookies also did not help.

I am not sure, why I am getting this error.

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: Please provided more details. Please add screenshot with your network traffic.

Comment: I've got similar problem with spring oAuth2. First one was incorrect url security configuration - url get redirected back to oAuth2 provider and since it is already logged in we get back to application to repeat the loop. Second, our app throws authentication exception on some condition and it get redirected to the first case - infinite redirect  loop. It is impossible to to see your problem without more details.

You can use browser Dev Tools to track the source of redirection.